# View cart page only if a user selects more than one product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to view cart page only if a user selects more than one product otherwise I want to redirect it to checkout page directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

// Add this code in header file.

if(is_cart()){        
    global $woocommerce;
    $total = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
    if($total<=1){         
      ?>
    <script>window.location="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('checkout'));?>";</script>
    <?php
    }
}
// Note: if You are selected 1 product 3 times the above code is not working.
?>
```